# What is the relationship between the 2d projection and a 3d point when using 1 point perspective?

Tags: projection

I understand the concept of $1$ point projection:

*As a $3d$ point gets closer to the vanishing point (further on the $z$ axis), the x and y values of the corresponding $2d$ screen point get closer to the $x,y$ of the vanishing point*.

I just don't know what this relationship is.

I assume it will include a $y = m/x$ relationship as the z position will never reach the z value of the vanishing point (infinity).
[How I think it will work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SHxYQ.png)

In the image I have a diagonal line from the projected point to the vanishing point labled d, for distance, and I think $d = 1/z$ (or some other constant in place of $1$). However, I don't know how I would calculate the values for $ScreenX$, and $ScreenY$.

Please don't give answers only in matrix form as I intend to use them in some code I am writing, and I'm not yet confident enough to turn matrices into single equations.

**Edit:** I think my question is asking the same as: [One-point perspective formula](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2337183/one-point-perspective-formula) and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56559793/one-point-perspective-and-point-with-negative-depth

Comment: If $\theta$ is the angle between d and the horizontal line, x=d $\cos\theta$, y=d $\sin\theta$.

Comment: But I don't know what theta is. (I know it is an angle)

Comment: If you know any two of d, screenx, screeny, you can get it, say screenx=1,screeny=1, then $\tan\theta$=1/1=1, $\theta$=45$^o$. check for details. https://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/trig-inverse-sin-cos-tan.html

Comment: I suppose I might be able to find θ between the 3d point's x,y, and the x,y of the vanishing point. I'll search for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was talking about this with some people on Discord and one gave me this answer: (I got permission to post it here)

> the correct function is: f(x,y,z) = (x/z, y/z)
>
> then z is the depth in the scene and you can move back and forward
> with f(x,y,z,t) = (x/(z-t), y/(z-t))
> where t is the camera z position
>
> generally, if you have a camera transformation, you apply that before the projection transformation
>
> f(x-a,y-b,z-c) = ((x-a)/(z-c),(y-b)/(z-c)) to translate the camera so that (a,b,c) is the origin
>
> later you might want to apply scaling or rotation to the camera.
> but notice that you subtract rather than add to translate the camera.
> the same rule applies to scaling and rotation.
> generally you transform by the inverse of the camera matrix before you project